One number grid, two ways to divide it (Part 2)
Find a rectangular grid of the smallest area that satisfies the following:

Each cell contains an integer between 1 and 4 inclusive.
The grid follows the Fillomino rule:

When the cells are divided into connected groups containing same numbers, each number belongs to a group of that many cells.


The grid follows the Sudoku-like rule:

It is possible to divide the cells into connected groups of 4 cells each, so that each group contains a 1, a 2, a 3, and a 4.



This is a sequel to my previous puzzle. I didn't have an answer for this version when I posted the linked one, but now I do.
Hint 1:

 A square-like grid is probably not the right choice.


Regarding the hint: rot13(Obgu nfcrpg engvbf unir fbyhgvbaf, gubhtu gur yrff fdhnevfu bs gur gjb nyybjf sbe, funyy jr fnl, pregnva nrfgurgvp dhnyvgvrf?)

@DanielMathias rot13(V unir n fbyhgvba sbe n yrff fdhnevfu tevq. V qba'g xabj vs n fbyhgvba sbe n zber fdhnevfu bar rkvfgf be abg.)

The least common multiple of 3 and 4 is 12, so the smallest grid must have 12 of each number, with a total area of 48 units. Three rectangular grids of this size have solutions.
The 3 x 16 rectangular grid:

 This is the first solution I found manually. It has 180 degree rotational symmetry.


The 4 x 12 rectangular grid:

 Symmetry is also possible on this grid. The first is one of two solutions with mirror symmetry, the second is one of ten with rotational symmetry.


The 6 x 8 rectangular grid:

 Symmetry is not possible with this grid, but this solution comes close.



The second 4x12 was exactly what I had got manually. Interesting to see solutions for all feasible dimensions.
